# Multiprocessing and niceness value

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Does anyone know of an easy way to set the niceness value of a Process or Pool when it is created in multiprocessing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
os.nice(increment)
Add increment to the process’s “niceness”. Return the new niceness. Availability: Unix.
```

From http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.nice.

Is there a reason you can't call this in the child process?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the ctypes module and looking for pthread_schedparam() or SetThreadPriority() (Linux / Windows).